# Class 'DateTimeImmutable' not found

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp, php-5.6

I've just run an update for my CakePHP version (3.1.7). And now I'm unable to run my app, with a fatal error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'DateTimeImmutable' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my-app/vendor/cakephp/chronos/src/Chronos.php on line 50
```

I found this [issue on Github](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/8525), where I noticed that

> DateTimeImmutable was not present in 5.4

So I install PHP5.6.20 on my PC, but after restarting Xampp, I still get the same error. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Well this is pretty straightforward error, is the class there?

Comment: Hi @skywalker. Really, there isn't any class file named 'DateTimeImmutable'. Though, the 'Chronos' class extends it.

Comment: Well there is your error, now you know you are missing a class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's installation on the PC is not related to Xampp. So installing PHP doesn't solve the problem. But installing a new version of Xampp with PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

It's a PHP Version Problem make sure You're using PHP > 5.5v